# Detect differentially expressing cells

Tags: rna, statistics, biostatistics

I have data (RNA expression values, obtained with in situ hybridization) collected from 1mio human cells. For each cell, I have the expression value of a negative control (non-human RNA) and single-cell measures for different RNA species. I know that the values from the negative control correlate in a linear fashion with all the other RNA species. For example, when a cell has a high expression value of the negative control, the signal for all other RNA species will also be high. I now want to detect the cells that express an RNA without having a high negative signal, e.g. the "real" expressing cells.

One thing to have in mind is that some RNA species are abundantly expressed in many cells, other are very rare and have a low expression value.

I tried to do this with a linear model (for each of the RNA species, negative control vs. single RNA), computing z-scores, infer p-values and correct for multiple testing. For some RNA species, it works just fine. As soon as I have many cells expressing a certain RNA, the thing gets more tricky because the slope of the linear model doesn't reflect the linear relationship of negative control vs. RNA species in non-expressing cells because it is more shifted towards the "real" expressing cells.

To visualize the problem, I attached two plots. One plot showing high RNA expression many cells (left plot) and one from an RNA species which is expressed on a very low level in few cells (right plot). Blue colored dots are considered as expressing cells according to the linear model. As you can see, for the scenario shown on the left side, many "real" expressing cells are not detected.

[image]

Any ideas which statistical model would better fit to detect those cells?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried just substracting the values for the negative control from each RNA species X? I think that should both improve your actual measurement and make it easier to detect with cells have non-detectable levels of the RNA.

Comment: good point @Nicolai, I will try that.. but how would you then define expressing cells? with a manual cut-off? I have to say that I'm not a big fan of manually defining things for such analyses because I think that will just introduce an unnecessary bias.

Comment: You can try linear mixed effects model. I'm not 100% sure if it would help but the cell to cell variability of the slope/intercept can be modelled as the random effect.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This question seems like it might be a better fit for the [Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @tyersome may be a better fit at [stats.se] but this isn't really a bioinformatics question.

Comment: @tebiwankenebi is the negative control and the expressed genes measured in the same cell (i.e. a two color FISH or something)? If not, you cannot simply subtract the negative control values. In that case, it is really not possible to differentiate a high false signal from a low true signal. However, if you consider each cell as a replicate population then would have to do some kind of two sample test or LM fit (using the expressed gene and negative control as predictors). LM may be less stringent than t-test or Mann-Whitney. Can you provide some more details on how you fitted the LM?

Comment: @WYSIWYG thanks for your answer. Yes, the expressed genes are measured in the same cell (it is actually multi-channel ISH). The linear model I use models Y = "mRNA of interest" ~ "negative control", assuming a linear correlation between the negative control signal and mRNA signal. I don't know if my approach is valid because I know that there is no linear correlation in real expressing cells (high mRNA, low negative control).